# html5 canvas img goes behind other drawn objects

Tags: javascript, html, image, canvas

I am creating a html5 canvas game and the main idea is that there is a loop at every animation that redraws everything on my canvas in every frame. 
For some reason the objects drawn don't appear in the order i want them to. i want the background image first, then a rectangle and finally an other image to be shown on top of each other.However, the rectangle blocks the view of the second image not other way around.

my relevant code:

```
function playerdraw(p){ 
ctx.rect(p.x,p.y,100,150);
ctx.stroke();
//irrelevant stuff here...
ctx.drawImage(p.im,p.x,p.y+25,100,100);
}
```

I run the whole thing on window.onload so image loading shoudn't be a problem.
Why is this happening?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I now know what my issue was. I forgot to add

```
 ctx.beginPath();
```

in my code. I called my function again and again and it drew more rectangles then I wanted to. I feel so silly.

Answer (score 0):

*(as you haven't provided enough code, I assume this could be the issue.)*

You need to redraw the background image each time you run the `playerdraw()` function *(if you're clearing the entire canvas each time)*. So, the following code should work :

```
function playerdraw(p) {
    // clear entire canvas
    ctx.clearRect(...);
    // draw background image
    ctx.drawImage(...);
    // draw rectangle
    ctx.rect(p.x, p.y, 100, 150);
    ctx.stroke();
    // irrelevant stuff here...
    // draw other image
    ctx.drawImage(p.im, p.x, p.y + 25, 100, 100);
}
```

**Note:** You need to clear the entire canvas at the very beginning *(if you're doing so)*. There's is also a possibility that you're doing some kind of canvas *translating* or *scaling* stuff which if done in wrong order, things can get pretty messed up.